# Epsilon-Delta definition theorem about coarser topologies

Tags: general-topology

I am having trouble proving the following claim (in either direction):

Let $d$ and $d'$ be two metrics on a set X, and let $\tau$ and $\tau '$, respectively, be the topologies that they generate. Show that $\tau$ is coarser than $\tau'$ if and only if for each $x\in X$, and $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that $B_{d'}(x,\delta)\subset B_{d}(x,\delta)$. Where $B_{d'}(x,\delta)$ denotes the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $\delta$ with respect to $d'$.

I know the following fact:

Let $X$ be a set. Let $A$ and $A'$ be two bases, generating the topologies $\tau$ and $\tau'$, respectively. Then $\tau$ is coarser than $\tau'$ if and only if for each $B\in A$ and each $x\in B$, there is a $B'\in A'$ such that $x\in B'$ and $B'\subset B$.

But I am not sure how to prove the claim. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use any bases. So why not take $A,A'$ to be the set of balls (as you have defined them) in each case?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\tau$ is coarser than $\tau'$.

Note that $B_d(x, \delta)$ (for any $x$, $\delta>0$) is $\tau$-open (because $\tau$ is the topology generated by the $d$-open balls), and so is also $\tau'$-open and so $x$ (which lies in that open set) must be an interior point (for $d'$) of $B_d(x, \delta)$ and this implies the existence of a $\delta'>0$ such that $B_{d'}(x,\delta') \subseteq B_d(x,\delta)$.

Suppose that the $\delta,\delta'$-condition holds and let $O$ be any $\tau$-open set. To see it is open for $\tau'$, it is enough to show

$$\forall x \in O: \exists r>0: B_{d'}(x,r) \subseteq O\tag{1}$$

by the fact that $\tau'$ is the topology generated by $d'$. To this end, let $X \in O$, and as $O$ is $\tau$- (hence $d$-)open there is some $\delta>0$ such that $B_d(x,\delta) \subseteq O$. Apply the condition and get a $\delta'>0$ such that 
$$ B_{d'}(x,\delta') \subseteq B_d(x,\delta) \subseteq O$$

and we're done showing $(1)$ (take $r= \delta'$). So $O$ is in $\tau'$ and $\tau$ is coarser than $\tau'$.